# problem in linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, radicals

I have the following equation, the problem is that there comes a time when I only have the x ^ 4 left and I don't know what to do next.

> x^4-1 = 0
>
> x^4 = 1
>
> ...

Does anyone know how the equation is still solved?

I had never done anything similar with exponents.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $x^4=1$ is not a linear equation, but the solutions are $x=\pm1$ in $\mathbb R$ and also $x=\pm i$ in $\mathbb C$.  $x^4-1=(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have to solve $x^4 = 1$. Substitute $u = x^2$ to get $u^2 = 1$. So $u = \pm 1$.

Thus, you now have to solve $x^2 = 1$ and $x^2 = -1$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I think so.

We will take this as a reference to keep moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Square root both sides: $\sqrt{x^4}=x^2=\pm 1\implies x^2=-1~\mbox{or}~x^2=1$.

$x^2=-1\implies \sqrt{x^2}=x=\pm\sqrt{-1}=\pm i$

and

$x^2=1\implies \sqrt{x^2}=x=\pm 1$

There are two real solutions ($1$ and $-1$) and two complex solutions ($i$ and $-i$).

Also could have factored using difference of squares:
$x^4-1=0\implies(x^2+1)(x^2-1)=0$ then solve each factor separately.

$x^2+1=0\implies x^2=-1$ and $x^2-1=0\implies x^2=1$, which are solved above.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $x^2=1$ has two solutions:  $x=\pm i$